# Custom objective function in XGBoost not overriding default

Tags: xgboost, loss-function, xgbclassifier

I am trying to implement this loos function [weighted_loss](https://github.com/jhwjhw0123/Imbalance-XGBoost/blob/master/imxgboost/weighted_loss.py), as a custom objective in XGBoost, using the sklearn XBGClassifier wrapper, as follows:

```
def weighted_binary_cross_entropy(dtrain, pred):
    # assign the value of imbalanced alpha
    imbalance_alpha = 90
    # retrieve data from dtrain matrix
    print('!!!!')
    label = dtrain.get_labe() ### BUG intentionally added here
    # compute the prediction with sigmoid
    sigmoid_pred = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-pred))
    # gradient
    grad = -(imbalance_alpha ** label) * (label - sigmoid_pred)
    hess = (imbalance_alpha ** label) * sigmoid_pred * (1.0 - sigmoid_pred)

    return grad, hess

xgb_test=XGBClassifier(obj=weighted_binary_cross_entropy).fit(X_trainnorm.to_numpy(), y_train.to_frame().to_numpy())

y_pred=xgb.predict(X_testnorm)
```

However, it seems to not be using weighted_binary_cross_entropy, since I put in the print statement and purposely added in a bug by dropping the `l` in label.

I've seen several posts about confusion wrt `obj` versus `objective`.

I noticed that for binary classification, use of `obj` supposedly only uses the default, so I tried this:

```
xgb_test=XGBClassifier(objective=weighted_binary_cross_entropy).fit(X_trainnorm.to_numpy(), y_train.to_frame().to_numpy())
```

but when I run it, I get:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_label'
```

I dug into the main module where I grabbed the custom loss function from, and see that dtrain is an xgb.DMatrix object (see [dtrain defined here](https://github.com/jhwjhw0123/Imbalance-XGBoost/blob/master/imxgboost/imbalance_xgb.py#L102)). Do I need to convert the numpy object to a DMatrix or is there a way to just use numpy arrays, espcially since the code snippet uses the native `train` method as opposed to the sklearn `fit` method.

Any insight to this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I got it passing `y_test` directly as `dtrain`:

```
def weighted_binary_cross_entropy(y_train, pred):
    # assign the value of imbalanced alpha
    imbalance_alpha = 90
    # compute the prediction with sigmoid
    sigmoid_pred = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-pred))
    # gradient
    grad = -(imbalance_alpha ** y_train) * (y_train - sigmoid_pred)
    hess = (imbalance_alpha ** y_train) * sigmoid_pred * (1.0 - sigmoid_pred)

    return grad, hess
```